# PrimeNG p-scheduler hourformat

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar, primeng

Since few hours I am trying to remove PM / AM from p-scheduler. It is based on fullcalendar.io. I tried to add totalHours attribute for 24 but didn't help. Also tried 100 other things. Did somone faced this problem?

```
<p-schedule [events]="events" [header]="headerConfig" [timezone]="local" hourFormat="24" defaultDate="2016-01-12"></p-schedule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not see an attribute of 'hourFormat' in its source code. https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/components/schedule/schedule.ts

Looks like it is using Full Calendar. You need to do something with its 'options'.
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/timeFormat/

Something like this:

```
<p-schedule ... options="{timeFormat: 'H(:mm)'}"
```